# Can I control or benefit from the ads showed up on my result page using the Google CSE?

Tags: google-programmable-search-engine

Google CSE is cool. And it's a very good replacement to the previous Site Search.

But I noticed that the ads on the result page is a bit annoying. Is it possible to remove them? Or is it possible to connect them to my Adsense account so that I can take a share of the revenue?

I tried to turn the settings in the "business" tab to "Do not show ads" but it's still there. Is there anything I did wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Connect your search engine to AdSense](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/4514267?hl=en) article you can connect Adsense Account to CSE:

> 1. From the control panel, select the search engine you want to edit.
> 2. Click Setup from the menu on the left and then click the Make money tab. Only owners, not administrators can access this tab.
> 3. Click the Search Engine Monetization button to turn it ON. Your AdSense publisher ID associated with your Google account will appear
>      on the page in a moment. Now, your Custom Search Engine is associated
>      with your AdSense Account.